# Can a Sql Server Full Text Catalog find the following?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-catalog

i have the following data in a field, which is being indexed by a `Full Text Catalog`.

> Pamorama City, Los Angeles,
>   California, United States

Simple. (I also have lots of others, but they are working fine).

Now, if the user provides this *incorrect, mispelt* search word

> pamorma city <-- notice the middle 'a'
>   is missing from the 6th character slot

then this data field isn't being returned.

So, can a **Sql 2008 FTS on a catalog return words which it THINKS it's close?**

this is the sql, btw, if this helps...

```
SELECT TOP(10) a.Address, AddressSearch.RANK AS TopRank
FROM Addresses a WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Addresses, FormattedAddress, 
                             'panorma NEAR city') AS AddressSearch 
        ON a.IdAddress = AddressSearch.[KEY]
```

If so .. can u also define a weight for 'close' words also? like a 90% match or something?
cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the T-SQL functions [SOUNDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) and [DIFFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx)?

Comment: Hmm.. DIFFERENCE might be a possibility :) I'll try and see if i can get some results of '4'. Hmm... Trying to use the result of a SOUNDEX looks very confusing.

Comment: I think I ended up spliting each word (delimeted by spaces and/or comma's) and search with an AND in the CONTAINS(..) .. I think :P